# NodeJs Connection Error querying SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am using this code to connect to my SQL Server and retrieve some data which works fine, if I only call the code once. If I call it twice I get this error:

> ConnectionError: Already connecting to database! Call close before connecting to different database.at ConnectionPool._connect

But I am closing the conn after the call so I'm not sure what I am missing.

```
var sql = require('mssql');

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
user: 'sa',
password: 'password',
server: '192.168.1.2',  
database: 'demo',
options: {
    encrypt: false 
}
})

var conn = pool;
module.exports.getCounter = function( query){             
conn.connect().then(function (err) {
    var req = new sql.Request(conn);
    req.query(query).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result.recordset);
        return result.recordset;
        conn.close();
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        conn.close();
    });
 })
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);

})};
```

Comment: Are you calling your `getCounter` function multiple times before a query's finished perhaps?

Comment: That might be the case as i read somewhere that all calls are asynchronous and for my test  just called  var myData = dbmssql.getCounter('select * from tbl_counters') a few times back to back

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS and SQL Server connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874447/nodejs-and-sql-server-connection-error)

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the value before closing the connection, hence the function terminates before reaching that line. So just move the `return` statement below your `conn.close()`. The other issues you might have afterwards is that you might be calling your function twice before one executes and terminates completely, since those calls are asynchronous.
You might have to set your getCounter function as a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so that you can wait for its completion/failure before calling it again. Off the top of my head in your example:

```
const getCounter = () => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
   conn.connect().then(function (err) {
    var req = new sql.Request(conn);
    req.query(query).then(function (result) {
        conn.close();
        resolve(result);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        conn.close();
        reject(err);
    });
 })
})
```

You can call your function afterwards as `getCounter().then((result) => {...})`

Answer (score -4):

Here is another way to solve it which might be helpful for others.

```
const sql = require('mssql')

let connectionPoolConfig = {
user: 'sa',
password: 'password',
server: '192.168.1.2',  
database: 'demo',
options: {
    encrypt: false 
}
}
let connectionPoolPromise = null
let connectionPoolObj = null

let getOrCreatePool = async () => {
if (connectionPoolObj) {
    return connectionPoolObj
} else if (!connectionPoolPromise) {
    connectionPoolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(connectionPoolConfig).connect()
}
connectionPoolObj = await connectionPoolPromise
return connectionPoolObj
}

let query = async(sql) => {
const pool = await getOrCreatePool()
return await pool.request().query(sql)
}

module.exports = {
query: query
}
```

And here is how to call it

```
let testCallerSQL = async () => {
try {
    const res = await sqlUtil.query('select * from mytable')
    console.log(res.recordset)
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
} finally {

}
}
```